# PHP Checking if timestamp is less than 30 minutes old

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm getting a list of items from my database, each has a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which i have changed into 'x minutes ago' with the help of [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/). So that's working fine. But the problem is i also want a "NEW" banner on items which are less than 30 minutes old. How can i take the generated timestamp (for example: 2012-07-18 21:11:12) and say if it's less than 30 minutes from the current time, then echo the "NEW" banner on that item.

Comment: I find it interesting how no one suggests using time()-30*60, wonder if I'm the only one used to work with unix timestamps as integers directly.

Answer (score 62):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)("-30 minutes") and then see if your row's timestamp is greater than that.

Example:

```php
<?php
    if(strtotime($mysql_timestamp) > strtotime("-30 minutes")) {
        $this_is_new = true;
    }
?>
```

I'm using strtotime() twice here to get unix timestamps for your mysql date, and then again to get what the timestamp was 30 minutes ago. If the timestamp from 30 mins ago is greater than the timestamp of the mysql record, then it must have been created more than 30 minutes go.

Comment: +1. Thanks. This is a better way of doing this than what I have been doing. I currently do: `if($post_date < (time()-600))` but using `strtotime()` but putting it in normal english is a bit easier than finding out the number of seconds to subtract :)

Comment: @user1511331 You should accept this answer (see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)) since it helped you.

Comment: @Orlo - Make sure your $mysql_timestamp is a date format that strtotime() understands.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this, using PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) object:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$then = DateTime($timestamp); // "2012-07-18 21:11:12" for example
$diff = $now->diff($then);
$minutes = ($diff->format('%a') * 1440) + // total days converted to minutes
           ($diff->format('%h') * 60) +   // hours converted to minutes
            $diff->format('%i');          // minutes
if ($minutes <= 30) {
    echo "NEW";
}
```

*Edit:* Mike is right, I forgot that for whatever reason, only `%a` actually returns the total of its type (in this case days).  All the others are for displaying time formatting.  I've extended the above to actually work.

Comment: This won't work. If the time difference is 1 hour 29 min, `$diff->format("i")` will be 29.

Comment: `$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H29M'); echo $interval->format('%i minutes');` echoes "29 minutes"

Comment: @Mike I forgot about that, and I suppose that's what I get for not actually testing the code.  I **did** test it this time and it works as expected.  =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also -

```
$currentTime=time();
```

to check the last updated time is 30 minute old or not

```
last_updated_at <  $currentTime - (60*30)
```