# PHP Check if the current time is less than a specific time

Tags: php, time

Let's say I got this time `21:07:35` now and this time into a variable `21:02:37` like this

```
<?php
$current_time = "21:07:35";
$passed_time = "21:02:37";
?>
```

Now I want check if `$current_time` is less than `5 minutes` then echo `You are online`
So how can I do this in PHP? 
Thanks
:)

Comment: Why not just set the session expiration to 5 minutes?

Comment: @Mike how can I set this, May you please specify exactly what do you mean? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370538/php-greater-than-certain-time

Comment: I have got the same problem @sam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To compare a given time to the current time:

```
if (strtotime($given_time) >= time()+300) echo "You are online";
```

300 is the difference in seconds that you want to check. In this case, 5 minutes times 60 seconds.

If you want to compare two arbitrary times, use:

```
if (strtotime($timeA) >= strtotime($timeB)+300) echo "You are online";
```

**Be aware**: this will fail if the times are on different dates, such as 23:58 Friday and 00:03 Saturday, since you're only passing the time as a variable. You'd be better off storing and comparing the Unix timestamps to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

```
$difference = strtotime( $current_time ) - strtotime( $passed_time );
```

Now `$difference` holds the difference in time in seconds, so just divide by 60 to get the difference in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Datetime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
//use new DateTime('now') for current
$current_time = new DateTime('2013-10-11 21:07:35');
$passed_time = new DateTime('2013-10-11 21:02:37');
$interval = $current_time->diff($passed_time);
$diff = $interval->format("%i%");

if($diff < 5){
 echo "online";
}
```

Comment: by using this datetime class, if the time now is 2013-10-11 22:03:45, your $diff will only get a value of 1 minute but in fact the time had passed 1 hour! Anyone can advise how to use this DATETIME class correctly?

Comment: This will give you correct minutes: 
`$diff = ($interval->format('%a') * 1440) + // total days converted to minutes
           ($interval->format('%h') * 60) +   // hours converted to minutes
            $interval->format('%i');          // minutes`
Original answer however available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549742/php-checking-if-timestamp-is-less-than-30-minutes-old) by @Crontab

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_time = "3:25:00";
$time_diff = strtotime(strftime("%F") . ' ' .$my_time) - time();


if($time_diff < 0)
    printf('Time exceeded by %d seconds', -$time_diff);
else
    printf('Another %d seconds to go', $time_diff);
```