# Login system - Call password check every load

Tags: php, performance, security

Currently I store the users password plain text in a session. Then I compare it using `password_verify($plain_password, $hashed_password);`. I believe it's really inefficient and poor security.

The second method could be to only check it once (and not store the password plain text in a session), and then store a boolean if the user was logged in or not. There's just one problem; What if the user changes password? Then the user would still be logged in on other devices, which of course is bad. Etc. the user might want to changed his password because he/she forgot to logout on a public computer.

How can I solve the problem of method two, and what is the 'correct' way to do it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just so you don't think I'm risking people's security. The application is not in use yet :)

Comment: You definitely are risking people's security. You should not be storing passwords in sessions. See the answer below. You need to compare times and using a DB if you're not using one already. Sessions are OK, so are cookies, just not to store passwords with.

Comment: I know. That was also why I asked this question, because I knew the security was bad. I would never use the application without knowing security was in top - That's my point :)

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/11549742/ it will show you some ideas. You need to check the differences in date/time last login.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, PostgreSQL or anything else? Don't store the passwords in the session; Store passwords in the User schema and the Session schema stays without passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store date of password change in db, and compare it to session created date. If pass was changed after session started you can cleer session user data

Comment: Do you think I should check every time or like every 5 minutes? (For performance)

Comment: I gess, if somebody is changing password it's propably because of some security reasons, so session should die immediately.